# How do I remove the KDE 4 Plasma Tool Box/cashew icon from the desktop?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I'm looking to remove the "Tool Box" icon in the upper right hand corner of my KDE 4 desktop, but can't find any configuration setting anywhere to do so. I'm new to KDE 4, so it's quite possible I just haven't found that setting yet.

Is there any way to remove that icon from your desktop, or is it just a permanent, unmovable part of KDE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can delete the `toolbox cashew widget` this way:

1. Open a terminal and type: `sudo -H dolphin` or `kdesudo dolphin` enter your password
2. In dolphin, navigate to `/usr/share/kde4/services`
3. Search in this folder for `plasma-toolbox`, there should be 3 files named `plasma-toolbox-(*something*).desktop`
4. Make backups of these in another folder and delete the originals
5. log out and back in

Done, no more cashew :)

Comment: This method did crash the UI, but after restarting all worked fine. I cannot accept that answer to 'how to remove something' is 'install something'.

Comment: This deserves more votes! The methods in the chosen solution used to work, but do not in 14.04. This answer does, and I have not seen it mentioned anywhere else, and I have been searching for a long time. Thank you!!

Comment: This also works for KDE 4 on Fedora 21

Answer (score 5):

Install [Py-Cashew](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Py-Cashew?content=147892) -- it's an additional script that removes the thingy (it can also be downloaded via KDE widget download tool)

There are also [Stealth Cashew](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Stealth+Cashew?content=108460) that let's you configure cashew transparency.

Comment: I installed Py-Cashew yet the cashew/"New Activity" items remains on my desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I found another alternative, in case anyone's interested: the "Stealth Cashew" widget also lets you hide the cashew. It requires the '`plasma-scriptengine-ruby`' package to work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "/usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-toolbox-desktoptoolbox"

1. Open terminal
2. Type: sudo rm /usr/share/kde4/services/plasma-toolbox-desktoptoolbox
3. Type your password (characters won't apper)
4. Relogin

Done. Checked. Worked.

Answer (score -1):

1) With the current Plasma design it is intended that the Toolbox is not easily removable because Plasma has a high configurability and the user always should have the possibility to get things back.

2) Still, the non-removable toolbox is a splinter in many user's eyes. So there is an ongoing discussion of how to let the user easily remove the toolbox while making sure there is always a way to "repair" a ill-configured desktop: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=285&t=125076